# Storing large number of files on server(s) - database or just filesystem?

Tags: python, database, web, flask

I'm working on a web application that requires a large number of user uploaded files of all types to be served. I'm unsure whether I should just store the files entirely in the filesystem and access them like that, or store the names or files themselves in a database. Which is quicker and which scales better? It might me stupid of me not to know this but I'm a complete beginner with this type of application, but how might I store multiple files with the same name in the filesystem, if I choose to go that route? For example, if two people uploaded different files, both named stuff.zip, how could I store them both in the filesystem and serve them? For image files I am replacing the filename with a shortened UUID, but for zips and documents and such I am sure users would actually like the files to retain their original names. Would I store the filename in a DB, change the filename on disk to a unique one, and then change it back when the file is served back up to a user/downloaded, or is there a simpler solution? Any recommendations of specific tools I should use? I'm making the application with Flask.

Comment: This really is a matter of opinion. Some store files in a database. I don't - I store files in the filesystem with a unique name and store that and the original name in the database. Choose a peg - hang your hat on it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd store the files on a file system, it seems inefficient to store them in a database which itself resides on a file system, unless you want to use any database specific features.

Furthermore you can use existing utilities on the files, with a database you'd have to extract them first.  For example the gzip utility can't directly read a file in a database but can read one on a file system.

As for the problem of multiple files, calculate the hash of a file from it's contents when it is uploaded. Then rename it based on the hash and store the filename-hash mapping along with the user ID and upload date in a database.  This has the advantage that if the same file is uploaded multiple times then you will only have one copy on disk.

Comment: I didn't mean that the actual files were duplicates, just the names. If two stuff.zip files were uploaded with different contents, how could I keep both files on one filesystem without a conflict, while retaining the original names? Is it viable to create a randomly named subfolder and then store the file in it, or will this just unecessarily complicate the system?

Comment: Hi, I was just pointing out the advantage of using file hashing if there are duplicates.  Forgot to mention that there is an overhead with hashing particularly with large files.  You could use randomly assigned names and directories and maintain a list of the appropriate mappings.  When a new file is uploaded just check that the random name hasn't already been assigned to a new file

Answer (score 1):

If you're performing full-text searches on the file contents (through database queries), then a database is the way to go.  Otherwise, it's an unnecessary burden on a database to act as a file system, and a burden on your DBA to maintain a bloated datastore.

If it's a file, treat it like one and store it accordingly.  Use a smart directory structure (like user/date/file.ext) so you can cluster files together, and move/delete them easily.